# save checkbox meta box and use it in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I made a checkbox meta box in my functions.php file but I have two problems. I can't save if checkbox is checked or not for the next times. and I want to show something in div if it was checked.

```html
<?php
    function filmview_ext_info_meta_box() {
     add_meta_box(
     'filmview_ext_info_meta_box',
     __( 'Extra info', 'filmview_ext_info_meta' ),
     'filmview_ext_info_meta_html',
     'filmview',
     'normal',
     'high'
     );
    }
    add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'filmview_ext_info_meta_box' );

    function filmview_ext_info_meta_html( $post) {
     wp_nonce_field( '_filmview_ext_info_meta_nonce', 'filmview_ext_info_meta_nonce' ); ?>

      <p>
      <input type="checkbox" id="filmview_ext_info_meta_sub" name="filmview_ext_info_meta_sub" <?php checked( $check, 'on' ); ?> />
      <label for="filmview_ext_info_meta_sub">Does it have subtitle?</label>
      </p>
     
     <?php
    }

function filmview_info_meta_save( $post_id ) {
 if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) return;
 if ( ! isset( $_POST['filmview_info_meta_nonce'] ) || ! wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['filmview_info_meta_nonce'], '_filmview_info_meta_nonce' ) ) return;
 if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post_id ) ) return;

$chk = isset( $_POST['filmview_ext_info_meta_sub'] ) ? 'on' : 'off';
    update_post_meta( $post_id, 'filmview_ext_info_meta_sub', $chk );
}
add_action( 'save_post', 'filmview_info_meta_save' );
?>
```

Comment: Seems like `$check` is never initialised but `$chk` it is ( BTW adding snippet doesn't work with back-end code )

Comment: I can't get it. How can I solve it?

Comment: You seem to initialiise the variable in a different function. Try my answer that I'll post

Answer (score 0):

What I can see is that:

1) You init `$chk` in the function: filmview_info_meta_save
2) You are using (with your provided code, an undefined variable ) `$check`

Try to read it from the database instead of of $_POST which is only present in the page after you submit the form, this should Do:

```
function filmview_ext_info_meta_html( $post) {
     wp_nonce_field( '_filmview_ext_info_meta_nonce', 'filmview_ext_info_meta_nonce' );
     $chk = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'filmview_ext_info_meta_sub', true);
     ?>

      <p>
      <input type="checkbox" id="filmview_ext_info_meta_sub" name="filmview_ext_info_meta_sub" <?php checked( $chk[0], 'on' ); ?> />
      <label for="filmview_ext_info_meta_sub">Does it have subtitle?</label>
      </p>

     <?php
}
```

Comment: As I have no tested it so right now I'm not sure If you need `$chk[0]` or just `$chk`

Comment: Could you post the output of `var_dump($chk)` ?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to change the variable name ( from a copy and paste ), please try my edit

Comment: that is : 'null'

Comment: 'string 'on' (length=2)' but it is't checked

Comment: have you tried just with `$chk` instead of `$chk[0]` ? ( my first comment mentioned that i'm not 100% sure )